# How to implement asynchronous retry mechanism in java 8?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, java-8, spring-retry

I'm using Java 8 Spring boot. I have below method.

```
public hello() {
  try {
    // send message
  }
  catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
     if (e.getRawStatusCode() == 401) {
          // I need to retry the same hello() method for three times as in 10sec, 20sec and 25sec.
     }
  }
}
```

I need to call the same method three times for retrying whenever it hits the catch block.
How can I do this asynchronously?

I found below code but it didn't work.

```
@Retryable( value = {RestClientException.class}, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(3000))
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Spring Retry fits your Usecase very well.   Refer here for more in detail  https://ashishontech.xyz/spring-retry-in-action/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retry mechanisms, you can to use the `@Retryable(value = RestClientException.class)`

For this to trigger, you need to actually throw this exception (or something that extends from RestClientException). Because of your catch statement, no exception is actually thrown, so the retry mechanism doesn't kick in.

```
@Retryable( value = {RestClientException.class}, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(3000)) 
public void hello() {
  try {
    // send message
  }
  catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
     if (e.getRawStatusCode() == 401) {
          throw new RestClientException("meaningfull message");
     }
  }
}
```

If you want to run some catch code after the 3 retries failed, you can make use of the `@Recover` annotation on a recovery method.

If you want some more info on the retry mechanism, you could look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)

Also don't forget to add `@EnableRetry` in your config so that the annotations are used.

### Full code example with spring boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    context.getBean(TestService.class).hello();
    context.close();
}

@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class AppConfig {
}

@Service
public class TestService {
    @Retryable(value = {IllegalArgumentException.class}, maxAttempts = 4, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 4))
    public void hello() {
        try {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(null);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exception triggered");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yoni thanks for your answer.
@Backoff(3000) will call the method excatly in 3seconds. 

So I tried with using  @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 3) which will retry the method in
1sec
1*3 = 3sec
3*3 = 9sec

Comment: That's indeed how it works for an exponential backoff. In my answer I used what you provided for backoff config. You can use a multiplier for exponential steps. You can also add a max delay, so that the exponential part will stop at a given max

Comment: `@Async
 @Retryable(value = {ServiceCallException.class}, maxAttempts = 4, backoff = 
       @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 4))
 public void hello() throws ServiceCallException {
  try {
   int a = Integer.parseInt(null);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
   throw new ServiceCallException("exception triggered");
  }
 }`

I use this code but retrying didn't happen

Comment: did you add `@EnableRetry` on your configuration class?

Comment: yes.
This gives me the exception and it stops there.

Comment: Do make sure that you are calling your method from another class, through the bean. Don't call it from within the class itself or from an instance you created with new. That won't work. I've added a full example with spring boot that works (on my machine)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `@Async` annotation from Spring to achieve that.
You have to create a config like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
@EnableAsync
class RetryConfig {}
```

When you want to use `Async` with `Retry` you have to decorate the method with `Async` which is trying to call a `Retryable` method. Also, you have to make sure that you are returning `Future<>` or similar because you are sending that piece of code for a toss in the background
I have also implemented fallback mechanism otherwise the request will terminate with 500 exception.

If you run the code below you can see that the main request is executed on thread `http-nio-8080-exec-1` while your Async code is executed on a different thread `task-1`.

I tried to explain this with a sample service method, but the concept will be same for local or remote service call.

A detailed exmaple is given below:

```java
package com.example.silentsudo.springcloudssamples;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Recover;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudsSamplesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudsSamplesApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RequestMapping(path = "sample")
@RestController
class SampleController {

    private final GreetService greetService;

    SampleController(GreetService greetService) {
        this.greetService = greetService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return "Hello!";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "greet")
    public String greet(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "John") String name) {
        return greetService.greet(name);
    }

    @Async
    @GetMapping(path = "greet-async")
    public CompletableFuture<String> greetAsync(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "John") String name) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(greetService.greet(name));
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableRetry
@EnableAsync
class RetryConfig {

}

@Service
class GreetService {

    private final UngaBungaService ungaBungaService;

    GreetService(UngaBungaService ungaBungaService) {
        this.ungaBungaService = ungaBungaService;
    }

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, value = GreetException.class, backoff = @Backoff(value = 3000L))
    public String greet(String name) {
        return ungaBungaService.lol(name);
    }

    @Recover
    public String recoverGreetException(GreetException greetException) {
        return greetException.getMessage();
    }
}

@Service
class UngaBungaService {
    public String lol(String name) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        throw new GreetException("Called greet for " + name);
    }
}

class GreetException extends RuntimeException {
    public GreetException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: silentsudo thanks for your answer.
Can you pls explain me why did you use @Recover method? In my case I need to call the same method for retrying.

Comment: I used recover method to recover from the failiure which will happen, as you can see it will throw GreetException, so instead of client getting exception i caught that and returned message from this because even after 5 attempt this call wont succeed as it is made for failure